# Does anyone knowhow to connect Genymotion cloud Paas (Virtual emulator) to vscode or react native CLI?

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I am able to connect the genymotion virtual emulator to Android studio but the emulator is not able to connect to VS Code or React native CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup VS Code and React Native CLI to use the same adb, from SDK platform-tools, as Android Studio.